# Primefaces inputTextArea maxlength not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 3.2. I have a text area with a maxlength set to 4000.
But the text area allows me to type 4001 chars. (Always one extra character).
I have been setting my maxlength to 3999 to avoid this problem 
Is this a known issue? I dont see this problem on showcase, any ideas?

```
<p:inputTextarea id="text" value="#{controller.text}" maxlength="4000"
                rows="6" cols="150" autoResize="true" required="true" requiredMessage="Text is required" rendered="#{controller.condition}"/>
```

Comment: do you see any errors in your browser console ? its perfectly working on IE/FF/Chrome , Try to upgrade to latest pf version

Comment: It happens in both FF and Chrome, i am using the same browsers to check the showcase as well. As Daniel mentions, it could be a PF version issue, i will upgrade to the latest and see if that helps

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes enter counts as 2 characters: \r\n instead of just \n.
In such cases try to replace all of these characters to \n in your setter method. You can do that for example by using StringUtils.replace() method:

```
your_string = StringUtils.replace(your_string, "\r\n", "\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using UTF-8 characters that take up more than one byte to store still counts as one character, but you can run into trouble with this in your database (getting an error message that it's more than 4000 characters).

You say it's always +1 character, check out using only ASCII characters (numbers+english letters).

ps: (if you are using nobleCount to display the remaing characters, it also has some issues with UTF-8 characters/some special characters).